# insert space between cells in list view javaFX

Tags: listview, javafx

I want to create gap between listview cells but i didn't find any suitable method to do this task.
Is there any method in css or java code to create gap between them?

Here is what I am looking for:

[image]
Thanks in advances,

Comment: Do you want to create gap between cells or gap between text and cell boundary?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha between cells

Comment: But, that in IMHO, is odd. ListView cells are made to be placed adjacent to each other. You should look at [this image](http://i.imgur.com/ZlMJLQP.png) in which I have just increased the space between the text and border. Here is the [default listview image](http://i.imgur.com/64TOXRE.png). If not, please add an image in support of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a "nested background" combined with padding in the css for `list-cell`. The following gives a result that is close to your screenshot:

list-view-cell-gap.css:

```
.list-view {
    -fx-padding: 3px ;
    -fx-background-color: darkred ;
}

.list-cell {
    -fx-padding: 2px ;
    -fx-background-color: transparent, -fx-background ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0px, 2px ;
}

.list-cell:empty {
    -fx-padding: 2px ;
    -fx-background-color: transparent ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 ;
}
```

Test code:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewStyleExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).mapToObj(Integer::toString)
            .map("Item "::concat).forEach(listView.getItems()::add);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(listView), 250, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("list-view-cell-gap.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which values should one adjust to either increase or reduce the margin? I needed some tangible margin and playing around with your approach does not seem to increased the margin